# Why is the lower bound 62?

Tags: ramsey-theory

Why is the lower bound of the minimum amount of points needed so that a $4$-coloring leaves at least one monochromatic triangle $62$, and not $66$?
A lower bound of $66$ would seem obvious, since it is $4*(17-1)+2$.
Would an explanation that doesn't require too much knowledge on the subject clarify this?

Comment: The lower bound of $R(3,3,3,3)$ is not $62$, the *upper* bound is $62$. Yes, $66$ is an easy upper bound, but $62$ is way better.

Comment: I did not say it was the lower bound of $R(3,3,3,3)$ but rather that there will definitely be a monochromatic triangle for numbers $\geq  62$. Could you explain why?

Comment: I think the problem is with "the lower bound." Or, if Casteels is right, "the upper bound." Basically, if $62$ is an upper bound, then so is $66$, and if $66$ is a lower bound, then $62$ is a lower bound. You can talk about "the greatest lower bound" or "the least upper bound," but there isn't in general one lower bound.

Comment: sorry, I mean the *greatest* upper bound for $R(3,3,3,3)$ then.

Comment: You're right I wasn't thinking about my terminology correctly. What I meant is that $R(3,3,3,3)$ is at most $62$ and so at most $66$. But $62$ is better.

Comment: Does anyone know why?

Comment: Here's [a paper](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~ricardo/r3333global.pdf) but  it's not trivial unsurprisingly: in general, improving a known good bound by even just $1$ is often cause for celebration.

Comment: So do you think I could find a more accessible explanation or probably not? Because I do not understand any of this notation/terminology.

Comment: It's certainly worth at least finding an example with 61 where this is not possible. That might not be so hard.